# How to use psycopg2-binary in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, database-connection, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

I installed the psycopg2-binary package using pip install psycopg2-binary. But when how can I use it in Python?

```
import psycopg2 as pg2
conn = pg2.connect(database = 'dvdrental', user = 'postgres', password = secret)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execure('select * from actor')
cur.fetchmany(5)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c2276cd20949> in <module>()
----> 1 import psycopg2 as pg2
      2 conn = pg2.connect(database = 'dvdrental', user = 'postgres', password = secret)
      3 cur = conn.cursor()
      4 cur.execure('select * from actor')
      5 cur.fetchmany(5)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
```

Comment: Are you running your scripts with the correct version of python (python2 versus python3) for which pip installed the module?

Comment: Hey jjanes, I'm using Python 3. It should be alright

Comment: For me `pip` has always installed for python2, and I had to use `pip3` to install for python3.  But  I suppose that may be a matter of configuration.  What is your OS and version and package manager?

Comment: I'm using MacOS Mojave, version 10.14.6. What do you mean by the package manager?

Comment: The package manager controls how you download and install software packages, and how they are configured to work together.  Popular package managers on Linux are apt, yum, zypper, and snap.  I don't know what the popular choices on Mac are.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Django on a Mac.  This is what worked for me.

In my virtual environment I ran:

> `pip install psycopg2-binary`

In `settings.py` I specified:

> ```
> DATABASES = {
>    'default': {
>        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
> ```

The database credentials have been left off.  I understand this isn't what the OP was asking about, but hopefully it will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu/Debian**

**pg_config** is usually installed by **libpq-dev**.

More details: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html

**Mac OS X**

Try using Brew Package manager for macOS(or Linux)
https://brew.sh/

```
brew install postgresql
```

**And if installed Postgres.app**

Then update the PATH as

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/14/bin
```

*Version can be checked via Applications->Postgres.app->Show Package Content->Contents->Versions->14*

Afterwards do

```
 pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: That worked for me. Though after installing postgresql I bumped into the next error which looked like this: `xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun`. This was further resolved by running `xcode-select --install`

Answer (score -1):

First install the dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get install build-dep python-psycopg2
```

And after that,

```
pip install psycopg2
```

Comment: I received `sudo: apt-get: command not found` message. I don't have the prerequisites for psycopg2, so that's why I installed psycopg2-binary

Comment: did you try? pip3 install psycopg2

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work. My pip is the latest version. ```Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wq/9xr6_qzd54b93xq2gjmqv6900000gn/T/pip-install-xs78x2zx/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.```

Comment: you have mac or windows or linux ?

Comment: I'm using Mac. For your reference, this is what I was looking at: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html